# Points of continuity of a function being dense

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $X$ is a metric space. A real valued function $f$ defined on a metric space $X$ is said to be of first baire class, if $f$ is a pointwise, limit of a sequence of continuous functions on $X$.

A famous well know theorem asserts that if *$f$ is in the first baire class, then the set of points of discontinuity is of the first category*.

<strike>Using this definition, can we characterize for what *Metric Spaces*, will the points of continuity of a real valued function, be dense in itself.</strike>

Ok, since we are talking about metric spaces, lets consider the 2 famous ones, complete and Compact. A compact metric space, is "Complete and Totally Bounded" by definition, so lets not look into it. So lets look at complete metric spaces.

So the question basically, is if, $X$ is a complete metric space, and $f$ is as above(1st Baire class), then is the points of continuity of $f$ dense in $X$.

There are some exercises related, but i didn't take it from here. So dont misunderstand me. http://books.google.com/books?id=CoSIe7h5mTsC&pg=PA166&dq=f+is+of+first+baire+class,+points+of+continuity

Comment: I am a bit confused by the statement of the question.  The warmup to the question features Baire class one functions, but the question itself does not.

Comment: Is that a quote from some homework assignment or some book?

Comment: @Asaf: No! Its not an homework!

Comment: @Asaf: While i was reading Baire category, theorem, i got this in my mind. Generally BCT talks abt the points of discontinuity, i asked why not ask something about the points of continuity of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The Baire category theorem asserts that in a complete metric space, a set of first category not only is not the whole space, but actually has dense complement.