# How to prove that there does not exist a sequence of continuous functions that converge pointwise to $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$ (definition only)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence, continuity

[A fellow member of the community asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590696/show-that-a-sequence-of-functions-does-not-exist):
"there isn't a sequence of continuous function on $[0,1]$ that converges pointwise to the function $f$ on $[0,1]$ defined by $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is irrational." This is the reverse of $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$, but the proof is obviously the same.

I'm wondering about a solution that only uses the definition of continuity and point-wise convergence. I answered the OP with the following attempt:

**Attempt 1:**
"
Suppose that $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a point-wise convergent sequence that converges to $f$. Let $x \in [0,1]$ and WLOG, suppose that $x$ is irrational.

Let $\epsilon>0$. WLOG, suppose that $\epsilon<1$.

1) Then there exists $N_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b>N_{1}$ imply that  $|f_{b}(x)-f(x)|=|f_{b}(x)-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

2) Since $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of continuous functions, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies that $|f_{b}(y)-f_{b}(x)|<\epsilon$ for each $y \in [0,1]$. Let $y \in [0,1]$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$. **Then** choose $p$ such that  $p \in \mathbb{Q}$, where  $x<p<y$.

4) Since  $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is pointwise convergent, there exists $N_{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a>N_{2}$ imply that  $|f_{a}(p)-f(p)|=|f_{a}(p)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

5) Let $N=\max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$. Suppose that $n>N$. By hypothesis, $|f_{n}(p)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|f_{n}(x)-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. However, by (3), we know that  $|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(p)|<\epsilon$. But this is clearly a contradiction."

However, this **doesn't work**, since it assumes that the same $\delta$ will characterize continuity for any $f_{n}$ where $n>N$.

**as a side-remark, is there any literature on the idea of a single $\delta$ working to describe continuity in a sequence of point-wise convergent functions $f_{n}$ for sufficiently large $n$?

**Attempt 3:** *sigh*, here is  another proof that ultimately rests on baire category for contradiction:

Let $\{f_n(x)\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions that converge pointwise.

We show that $A=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid f_n(x) \textrm{converges}\}$ is a Borel set [and more specifically, $G_\delta$.

If $x \in A$, then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $n,m \geq N$ implies that $V_{x,n,j}=|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\frac{1}{j}$ for each $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Then Let $V_{n,j}=\bigcup V_{x,n,j}$. Since $V_{n,j}$ is open, let the open set $U_{n,j}$ be defined by $U_{N,J}=F^{-1}(V_{n,j})$. But then
$$\bigcap_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n,m \geq N} U_{n,j}=A$$
 is $G_\delta$

Then use Baire category to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not $G_\delta$, and so the result follows.

**I'm still interested in a proof that does *not* use this, and also in a possible proof verification for my proof given in the answers section.**

Comment: Equicontinuity captures the notion of "the same $\delta$ working for every function." See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity

Comment: I don't think the Baire Category Theorem is "unnecessary machinery" here. If $f$ is a pointwise limit of continuous functions then $f^{-1}\{0\}=\{x : f(x)=0\}$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set. The simplest way to show that $Q$ is not $G_{\delta}$ is to use Baire.

Comment: I know it is the easiest and simplest way. However, I'm just wondering about an alternative method.

Comment: Would [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1444407) satisfy you? Other copies of this question might be worth checking, too. Some of them can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/77307) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1590696).

Comment: @user254665 only now do I understand your concern for what is probably as simple a proof as one can muster up. For some reason, there is some part of me that *still* cannot let go of the fact that there is something more fundamentally wrong with the notion of this particular convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to show that $ Q$ is not $G_{\delta}$ in $R$ without the Baire Category theorem:

(1).A non-empty completely metrizable space with no isolated points is an uncountable space.(In fact it has a subspace homeomorphic to the Cantor set.)

(2).A subspace $Y$ of a completely metrizable space $X$ is completely metrizable iff $Y$ is $G_{\delta}$ in $X.$

Therefore, since the space $Q$ has no isolated points, it cannot be completely metrizable, else by (1)  it would be uncountable. So by  (2), $Q$ is not $G_{\delta}$ in $R.$

Both (1) and (2) are provable by elementary, but not brief, methods, without any reference to the Baire Category theorem.

Comment: This is a fascinating point! (1) is a theorem in Munkres' *Topology*. I will work on the second bit! Thank you

Comment: The direction of (2) needed here, that if Y is completely metrizable  then Y is G-delta in X, is easier than the other direction.  There is another result proved very much like the proof of  (1): If X is locally compact,Hausdorff, non-empty and has no isolated points then X has a compact subspace of cardinal at least |R| (the cardinal of the reals).

Comment: I will accept this answer, as it does indeed answer the question, and it does not seem as though any new suggestions will come.

Comment: (2) is best done in stages: 1. If $X$ is metrizable , $Y$ completely metrizable  with $Y\subset X,$  then $ X$ \ $\bar  Y$ is $F_{\sigma} in X.$ .And  show that $\partial Y$ is $F_{\sigma}$ in $X$.... (2). If $X$ is Hausdorff and $F=\{f_n:n\in N\}$ is a set of completely metrizable subspaces of $X,$ let $d_n$ be a complete metric on $f_n$ with $\sup f_n\leq 1.$  Show that $\sum_{n\in N}2^{-n}d_n$ generates the subspace topology on $\cap F$ and is a complete metric.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer, I received some assistance from a friend of mine. Slight question: does it depend implictly on any non-stated theorems (I mean, so called "big theorems.")

Suppose that $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a point-wise convergent sequence that converges to $f$. 
Let $a,b \in [0,1]$ such that $0<a<b<1$. We will show that for each non-degenerate segment $A \in [0,1]$, there exists some $B \subseteq A$  and arbitrarily large $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_{N}(B) = [a,b]$.

Let $A$ be a non-degenerate segment of $[0,1]$. Let $y \in (\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})\cap A$ and $x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap A$ such that $x < y$. Since $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges pointwise to $f$, we have that there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_{N}(x) \geq b$ and $f_{N}(y) \leq a$. But since $f_{N}$ is continuous,by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists some $ B \subseteq [x,y] \subseteq A \subseteq [0,1]$ such that $f_{N}(B)=[a,b]$.

Then consider the embedded sequence of $\{A_{n}\}$, where $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_{n}$. Clearly for each $A_{n}$ there exist respective $K_{n} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_{K_{n}}(B_{n})=[a,b]$ for $B_{n} \subseteq A_{n}$. By the nested interval theorem, the intersection of $A_{n}$ is non-empty. Then let $x \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_{n}$. But then $f(x)$ is the limit of $f_{n}(x) \in [a,b]$, which is a contradiction since $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=1$ and $0<a<b<1$.

**edit: i think this proof is incorrect since it makes little reference to the rationals (Although I suppose it assumes denseness.)

Comment: It IS correct, Consider that both $\mathbb Q$ and its complement are both dense. You can replace $\mathbb Q$ with any $S$ which is dense and co-dense.

Comment: Well that is quite heartening! It has been a while since I thought about this, but retrospectively, I don't see anything wrong either. Interesting remark of yours, I suppose that dense and codense would he sufficient to generalize this proof.